# Add settings or configuration file to TFS Extension development

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, vssdk

Im developing tfs extension to Azure DevOps 2020 using VSS SDK and I would like to make some variables configurable using concept like environment variables, settings page or configuration file (maybe the extension manifest json file). is it possible to read from the application, maybe using the tfs sdk, thus variables to make the extension more generic and dynamic?

Comment: You mean you want to read environment variables, settings page or configuration file in your custom extension? If yes, I think it is possible, you can try to refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops-2019#scopes

Comment: I think the question may be closer to storing settings / configuration. for that you can look at this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/data-storage

Comment: That in no exactly what Im looking for, I want the ability to deploy my custom extension with different settings so when my extension will load and run it will read thus settings and perform according to them. just like a program that read env variables.
Im willing to deploy it with some configuration file even before the publish step so anyone can adjust his own settings before he install the extension.